# How do get the Ubuntu install disk to show all drives

Tags: ssd, 18.10, drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu18.10 in a dual boot with Windows 10, the only problem is them my Ubuntu install disk isn't showing my SSD. I watched a tutorial online about how to install Ubuntu, from what I know there are two options. Ether I can manually partition my disk or I can let Ubuntu do it for me, I'm much more comfortable letting Ubuntu do it for me as I know very little about this. I have Windows 10 installed on a separate SSD in my computer and I want to install Ubuntu on another SSD in my computer. what's should happen is after you press "Install Ubuntu alongside operating systems" is a list of your drives should show up, letting you pick which drive to install your OS on. The list isn't showing up and I have no idea what to do. The SSD has been used before so if that means anything there you go. So how do you get Ubuntu to show the disks it can install on? Thanks!

Comment: Many SSD need firmware updates, and UEFI needs update from your system vendor. But issue most often is Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI If two drive install, really better to partition in advance. See this but new versions of Ubuntu do not now need swap partition, just ESP - efi system partition & / (root), but often better to have smaller / and larger /home and/or data partitions.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: There are a few things tutorials rarely mention: 1. It's recommended to reserve unallocated space for Ubuntu by shrinking partitions in **Windows** and reboot again to Windows to make sure it's fine. 2. Windows Fast Startup should be disabled followed by a shutdown  3. In cases such yours the SATA mode in UEFI must be changed to AHCI, otherwise the drives won't be correctly detected and AHCI drivers must be previously installed in Windows or it won't boot after the mode change.

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

You've got a single SSD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem.

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:

  - Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
  - Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`

  - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`

  - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.